# NodeJS - How to open a web page using terminal in browser and run a script on the opened page

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, console

I want to open a page like `http//google.com` with browser using a NodeJS script ran in my terminal; And run this code in that page: (like when open console in chrome browser and write some JavaScript code)

```
const allDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log('allDiv', allDiv.length);
```

I know some npm packages like [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) opens a web page with windows(my os) browser, but my question is: how to run a JS script in that page?

(In advance, I want to use `window.scrollBy()` function to scroll down the opened page.)

Comment: Have a look at [selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @gurisko Thanks. it was helpful. but I want to access the `window` and `document` directly like it is in browser console. I want to use `window.scrollBy()` function to scroll down the opened page. something robotic!

Comment: @AliAmini You can do that using selenium - the `JavascriptExecutor` allows you to execute any javascript in the browser you want. You can also use the core selenium methods to find elements on the page.